Limit of sequence in $C_b(\mathbb{R})$
Consider $C_b(\mathbb{R}) = \{f| f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}, f \text{ is continuous and bounded}\}$ with norm $\lVert\cdot\rVert_\infty$. For $f\in C_b(\mathbb{R})$ define $\displaystyle g_n(x) = n(e^{-\frac{1}{n}x^2}f(x) - f(x))$. It is obvious that $\forall x\ g_n(x)\rightarrow -x^2f(x) \ (n\rightarrow\infty)$. Is it true that $\lVert g_n+x^2f\rVert_\infty\rightarrow0$ for all $f$ such that $x^2f \in C_b(\mathbb{R})$? If not, how to find all functions $f$ such that this limit equals zero?
This question appears while trying to calculate the generator $L$ of semigroup of operators $T_tf(x) = e^{-tx^2}f(x), f\in C_b(\mathbb{R})$.
$Lf(x) = -x^2f(x)$, but there is a question how to find its domain.

If $x^4f \in C_b(\mathbb{R})$ it should be true.

It is not true for all $f$ with $x^2f \in C_b(\mathbb{R})$ (take the sequence $x_n = \sqrt{n}$ to see that it does not always converge uniformly).

As pointed out by psl2Z, taking $f(x)=1/(1+x^2)$, we can see that the convergence is not uniform on the real line, since the value at $x_n=\sqrt{n}$ does not converge to $0$.
However, if $\lim_{\lvert x\rvert\to\infty}x^2f(x)=0$, then the convergence is uniform on the real line. Indeed, for a fixed $\varepsilon$, pick $R$ such that if $\lvert x\rvert>R$, then
$\lvert x^2f(x)\rvert<\varepsilon$. One has
$$
\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}\left\lvert g_n(x)+x^2 f(x)\right\rvert\leqslant 
\sup_{x:\lvert x\rvert\leqslant R}\left\lvert g_n(x)+x^2 f(x)\right\rvert
+\varepsilon\sup_{x:\lvert x\rvert>R}\frac{(1-e^{-x^2/n})n+x^2}{x^2}.$$
Noticing that $\sup_{t>0}(1-e^{-t})/t=:M$ is finite, we find
$$
\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}\left\lvert g_n(x)+x^2 f(x)\right\rvert\leqslant 
\sup_{x:\lvert x\rvert\leqslant R}\left\lvert g_n(x)+x^2 f(x)\right\rvert
+(M+1)\varepsilon.
$$
Similar computations as those which led to the point wise convergence show that the convergence is uniform on each compact interval.
